# How to execute an object's internal function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, class, ios4

So I am pretty new to object oriented programing, and I am trying to do the following in xcode - I have a MyMap.m view controller where I display your location, and now want to add weather. For this purpose I would like to send the coordinate to a geocoder class that will return first the zipcode. I decided to heat it up with the classes, so created a class which will return the zipcode.

the code in the map controller is:

.....

```
  MKPlacemark *zip;
    getzip = [[GetZipcode alloc] init]; //ADDED THIS

[getzip reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation];
zip = getzip.myPlacemark;
NSLog(@"Placemark is: %@", zip);
```

....

where getzip is an instance of a GetZipcode class:

```
@interface MyMap : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MyLocationControllerDelegate> {

              GetZipcode *getzip;
 //and more stuff
 }
```

From some reason, nothing happened when I run this:

```
[getzip reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation];
```

which reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation is a function inside the GetZipcode class:

.h

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation;
```

and the .m of that class is:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation
{
self.reverseGeocoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] init] autorelease];
reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
[reverseGeocoder start];
}



- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
PlacemarkViewController *placemarkViewController = [[PlacemarkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlacemarkViewController" bundle:nil];
placemarkViewController.placemark = placemark;
myPlacemark = placemark;
NSLog(@"Placemark is: %@", placemark.postalCode);
 }
```

Hope it's not TMI, but would really appreciate some help here. thanks!

Comment: I don't see any code where you instantiate getZip. Also, you cannot expect it to have a placemark directly after starting the reverseGeocoder; that's not how this kind of service works - which you might have guessed, seeing as you implemented a method that gets called *when the reverse geocoder finds something*. Before the reverse geocoder returns with a placemark, you ask your object for the placemark (the reverse geocoder runs alongside your application; the app does not wait for it to return).

Comment: Isnt this the way to instantiate getZip? (see above):               GetZipcode *getzip; which I do on the header file of the object that uses getzip?

Comment: Looks like my callback (reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark)is not being called - any ideas?

Comment: A few basic concepts: Creating a variable (in this case, an instance variable or short iVar) is just reserving a seat for an object with a nametag on it. An object is an instance of a class. So you have declared an empty seat, but you have not created an object to sit there. You typically create objects by calling `[SomeClass alloc] init...]` methods. Some classes provide convenience methods that return an initialized object to you, like `[UIColor blackColor]`, but behind the scenes, they basically also do the alloc init stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give the MKReverseGeocoder a coordinate to reverse geocode.

The designated initializer is -[MKReverseGeocoder initWithCoordinate:] through which you supply the coordinate.

Hope that helps

(also of course check to see that you created and init'd your GetZipcode instance and that getzip isn't nil when you try to use it.)

**EDIT:**

You created an instance variable (ivar) called getzip. But you didn't post any code that creates an instance of GetZipcode and puts that address in the pointer getzip. Somewhere you should have something like:

```
getzip = [[GetZipcode alloc] someAppropriateInit];
```

**SECOND EDIT**

So a couple more things to think about here. (1) You can't actually read the placemark property immediately as you trying to do here:

```
zip = getzip.myPlacemark;
```

It will take some time for a reverse geocoder to go out to the network and do it's work and figure out the placemark. So you won't have a placemark until you get the delegate callback:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
```

(2) You should also implement this callback so you can see if there was a problem finding the placemark:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

(3) Are you sure you are passing a valid coordinate to the reverse geocoder? You may want to log that to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Initialized it now, but this doesnt solve the problem. I also see that both of you said to instantiate the getZip, but I do do that (above in the second code box). Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No, the second code block shows you reserved space for an instance variable called getzip. But you didn't create any GetZipcode object in the code you posted. Can you update the code to make sure we're looking at the same thing?

Comment: Added this instantiation above. Now it "enters" the object, but doesnt return the zipcode. I guess @fzwo is right here - but I am not sure how to run the methods properly.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, that was VERY helpful! Know I am getting into this object, and into the didFindPlacemark, but how to I return the placemark back to the parent object? (where I instantiated the GetZipcode object). Thanks again!!